# Can e-paper capsules be made larger in size?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Can I buy individual (larger in size) e-paper capsules from somewhere? (for an electronics project for example) and is it even possible for such large e-paper capsules to be engineered?

Comment: Available from 1.1 to 42 inch, see https://www.beck-elektronik.de/produkte/displays/e-paper-display-epd/active-matrix-epd/?gclid=CjwKCAjwpuXpBRAAEiwAyRRPgbfl0sIHf_6nncCyth19cPzUR4rp1Jja1N98O0AanUSUsVwi6Cwo7xoCJB4QAvD_BwE

Comment: Great but I need to be able to buy individual capsules, not displays.

Comment: Just like you can buy individual LEDs, and not only displays.

Comment: Well, it might give you sufficient information to do a more effective google search, as you don't explain much of what you want to achieve so excluding the possibility of us being able to suggest alternatives. Good luck with your project.