# How would I go about charging titanium dioxide for e-paper technology project?

Tags: electrical-engineering, chemistry

I'm experimenting with rubbing a balloon on a silk (to get the electrons) and then touching the balloon to two small aluminium foil balls to see if they'll repel but they don't (if I do it with aluminium foil sheets, they stick to the balloon for some reason, and again, they don't repel). What's happening here?

My final goal is to charge titanium dioxide powder by rubbing a charged balloon in the powder. (I don't know if that will work though)
Is that cheapest way to go about doing this?

Comment: This project? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/29358/10902

Comment: Are you the same user that posted that? Curious, same name but seem to be different accounts...

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts